# c++ makefile explanation (dependencies and macros used in it)?

Tags: c++, makefile

I wrote the following makefile, but I don't really understand what's going on (I based the instructions off of a template). I wrote the following makefile, but I don't really understand what's going on (I based the instructions off of a template).

1) Why does the DEPENDS macro have that specific information on the
    right hand side? I thought the object files were dependent only on
    .h files?

2) Why do we have to specify ARCH?

3) Why do we need the flag -IStanfordCPPLib in CPPOPTIONS? I understand that we need the flag 
-lStanfordCPPLib for LIB as this macro specifies the location of the .a file which has all the .h files used, but I'm not sure why LIB isn't used as a dependency for RandomWriter.o then?

4) Any explanation of significance and functionality of CPPOPTIONS and LDOPTIONS would also be appreciated

```
PROGRAM = RandomWriter
OBJECTS = RandomWriter.o
DEPENDS = \
   RandomWriter.cpp \
   Makefile

ARCH = i386
CPPOPTIONS = -IStanfordCPPLib -arch $(ARCH) -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
LDOPTIONS = -LStanfordCPPLib -arch $(ARCH)
LIB = -lStanfordCPPLib

all: $(PROGRAM)

RandomWriter : $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -o $(PROGRAM) $(LDOPTIONS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIB)

RandomWriter.o : $(DEPENDS)
    @touch console.h
    g++ -c $(CPPOPTIONS) RandomWriter.cpp
    @rm console.h

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.a $(PROGRAM)
```

Comment: There is nothing special about the make veriables themselves. They are just being used to hold strings that are later used in other contexts. In this case they fold flags for g++ so `CPPOPTIONS` is just holding a set of g++ flags.

Comment: Furthermore, there *are* some special variables, which get used for implicit rules. But none of these are being used in youe Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The object file depends on anything that is used to compile it. I suspect in this case there may not be a header file, otherwise the dependency would be on the `.cpp` **and** on the header. If you have a header, you should add it to the dependencies.

2) ARCH allows you to compile for a target of a different of the architecture family. For example, 64 bit vs. 32 bit. You may find `ARCH` used for cross-compilation too, in which case the `Makefile` would switch the toolchain based on the value of `ARCH` (e.g. replace `g++` for something like `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++`) as opposed to using the `-arch` compiler flag. You should check what target architecture you want and decide whether you need this.

3) `-IStanfordCPPLib` means directory `StanfordCPPLib` will be used in the include search path. It is needed because the compiler has to be able to find the includes necessary to compile `RandomWriter.o`.

4) `CPPOPTIONS` look like compiler options, `LDOPTIONS` look like options for linking. You can see that the former are used to build the `.o` file, and the latter to link the executable.

See [the GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for more information.

Comment: Btw, why might we want to include a `Makefile` itself as a dependency for `.o`? Looks rather pointless to me.

Comment: @MaximSkurydin I guess if you change the Makefile you might want to rebuild. I must say I haven't done that before.

Comment: It actually makes sense to have objects dependent on Makefile. Like this, when you change compiler and/or linker options (CPPOPTIONS or LDOPTIONS in this case), all objects will be rebuilt using the new options. Otherwise you might end up with object files that were compiled with incompatible options. For larger projects you should dive deeper into this topic so you can have automatic dependency creation etc.